# How can I change json by having a path to a place in the string?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a problem. An existing project requires a json change, before that I used jmespath and everything was fine, but now I need to add to json, I tried to do it like this:

```
str = "d[\'start\']" + path[5:len(path)-4].replace("child", "[\'child\']").replace("[*]", "").replace(".", "")
str = str[:len(str)-9]+".append(child:[{'cmd': get_result_from_db(id), 'message': result}])"
print(str)
exec(str)
json.dump(d, f,indent=4)
```

I opened json earlier like this:

```
with open('info1.json', encoding="cp1251") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

I understand that the first piece of code looks wild, but it doesn't throw exceptions until `exec(str)`
I checked, my path is parsed correctly, and here is the exception itself:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

And I understand that append is not applicable to lists, but how can I upload changes to json?

P.S
I will give an example of the structure of a json file

```
{
  "start": [
    {
      "cmd": "1",
      "message": "main",
      "child": [
        {
          "cmd": "1",
          "message": "something."
        },
        {
          "cmd": "3",
          "message": "this"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add a `child:[{'cmd': get_result_from_db(id), 'message': result}]` to the place where `"message": "this"`.
How can I do this with a json path to the desired location?

Comment: Please modify your posting to make a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: Do you or do you not have a JSON string representing your object? I am trying to determine the point of your string manipulation and the call to `exec(...)`. If you do have a JSON representation, then do `d = json.load(...)` then modify d like any other variable, then do `json.dump(d)` to get it back to a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to browse the dictionary using the keys:

```
dict.get ("key")
```

Once you find yourself in the right dictionary you just have to add your new dictionary using:

```
dict.update ("key": "value")
```

I hope I understood your problem and helped you

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample JSON file, this will add another list entry to `"child"`:

```py
import json

def get_result_from_db(id):
    return id * 2

result = 'some result'

with open('info.json',encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

to_add = {'cmd':get_result_from_db(1), 'message':result}
data['start'][0]['child'].append(to_add)
print(json.dumps(data,indent=2))
```

```
{
  "start": [
    {
      "cmd": "1",
      "message": "main",
      "child": [
        {
          "cmd": "1",
          "message": "something."
        },
        {
          "cmd": "3",
          "message": "this"
        },
        {
          "cmd": 2,
          "message": "some result"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this was the solution to the problem

```
place_path = "d[\'start\']" + path[5:- 4].replace("child", "[\'child\']").replace("[*]", "").replace(".","")
place_path += "['child']={'cmd': get_result_from_db(id), 'message': text}"


exec(place_path)
```